# How do free contacts from Professional Training work?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, hunter-the-vigil

The wording of the merit in **Hunter: the Vigil** is ambiguous (along with the example.

> In game terms, the character is considered to have the Contacts Merit (see p. 114 of the World of Darkness Rulebook) equal to her rating in Professional Training, in addition to the other benefits that later levels provide. **Every time a hunter character gains a dot of Professional Training, the player must choose a subfield of the Profession for this portion of the Merit**

If I have •• in professional training, do I have:

1. One 'contact' merit at ••, with the more specific subfield (as per the example, the Police version goes and Federal Agents is chosen)
2. Two 'contact' merits, one at • and one at •• (Police, and Feds respectively)
3. Two 'contact' merits, both at •• (Police, and Feds)

Which is it?

Comment: This question is specific to the **New** world of darkness, not the old one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Number three is most correct.**

Your Professional Expertise •• functions like Contacts •• (Police, Federal Agencies).

The difference between the two is that *unlike* Contacts, the subfields must be subcategories of the profession. (Unlike Allies and Retainer, Contacts is a *single* merit, with each dot reflecting a different field of inquiry — see the nWoD rulebook on page 114 for more on that.) You can take Contacts as well, reflecting a broader range of people and interests.

For example:

> Professional Training •• allows you to roll Manipulation + Persuasion or Socialize to find information from members of two groups, both of which need to be connected to your area of professional expertise. This mirrors the effect of Contacts ••

Comment: By one, do you mean three(rather than losing one you just gain the other as I misinterpreted the Contact merit)?

Comment: Er, yes. Professional Training •• allows you to roll Manipulation + Persuasion or Socialize to find information from members of two groups, both of which need to be connected to your area of professional expertise. This mirrors the effect of Contacts ••. Whatever number that is closest to is correct.